# Vue router - The "next" callback was called more than once in one navigation guard

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am using Vue 3 with Vue router 4. I have created middleware functions that my routes have to pass through but for some reason Vue is throwing this error:

> The "next" callback was called more than once in one navigation guard when going from "/" to "/protected". It should be called exactly one time in each navigation guard. This will fail in production.

Here is my routes file:

```
import auth from '@/middleware/auth'
import admin from '@/middleware/admin'
import initRoutesMiddleware from '@/routes/middleware'
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: () => import('@/views/DashboardView.vue'),

        meta: {
            middleware: [ auth ],
        },
    },

    {
        path: '/protected',
        name: 'protected',
        component: () => import('@/views/ProtectedView.vue'),

        meta: {
            middleware: [ auth, admin ],
        },
    },

    {
        path: '/access-denied',
        name: 'accessDenied',
        component: () => import('@/views/error/AccessDeniedView.vue'),
    },
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: routes,
})

router.beforeEach((_, __, next) => {
    setAppLoadingCursor(false)
    
    return next()
})

initRoutesMiddleware(router)

export default router
```

Here is my `middlware/auth.ts`:

```
import { ROUTE_LOGIN } from '@/config/routes'
import { LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_USER, LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_PATH_BEFORE_LOGIN } from '@/config/app'

export default function auth({ to, next }: any) {
    const user = !!localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_USER)

    if (!user) {
        localStorage.setItem(LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_PATH_BEFORE_LOGIN, to.path)

        return next(ROUTE_LOGIN.path)
    }

    return next()
}
```

and here is `middleware/admin.ts`:

```
import AppUser from '@/types/appUser'
import { LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_USER } from '@/config/app'
import { ROUTE_ACCESS_DENIED } from '@/config/routes'

export default function admin({ next }: any) {
    const user = localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_USER)
    
    if (!user) return next()

    const appUser: AppUser = JSON.parse(user)

    if (appUser.admin !== true) return next(ROUTE_ACCESS_DENIED.path)

    return next()
}
```

Here is `routes/middlware.ts`:

```
import { Router, RouteLocationNormalized, NavigationGuardNext } from 'vue-router'

interface RouteContext {
    from: RouteLocationNormalized
    next: NavigationGuardNext
    router: Router
    to: RouteLocationNormalized
}

function nextFactory(context: RouteContext, middlewares: Function[], index: number) {
    const subsequentMiddleware = middlewares[index]

    if (!subsequentMiddleware) return context.next

    return (...parameters: any[]) => {
        context.next(...(parameters as []))
        const nextMiddleware = nextFactory(context, middlewares, index + 1)
        subsequentMiddleware({ ...context, next: nextMiddleware })
    }
}

export default function initRoutesMiddleware(router: Router) {
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        if (to.meta.middleware) {
            const middlewares: Function[] = Array.isArray(to.meta.middleware)
                ? to.meta.middleware
                : [to.meta.middleware]

            const context: RouteContext = { from, next, router, to }
            const nextMiddleware = nextFactory(context, middlewares, 1)

            return middlewares[0]({ ...context, next: nextMiddleware })
        }

        return next()
    })
}
```

Comment: I think the problem lies in you calling the next() on !user checking in both auth and admin functions, so it got called twice... how about separating this check?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (see below for more info):

`routes/middleware.ts`

```
import { Router, RouteLocationNormalized, NavigationGuard } from "vue-router";

type GuardFn = (
  to: RouteLocationNormalized,
  from: RouteLocationNormalized
) => ReturnType<NavigationGuard>;

export default function initRoutesMiddleware(router: Router) {
  router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
    if (to.meta.middleware) {
      const middlewares: GuardFn[] = Array.isArray(to.meta.middleware)
        ? to.meta.middleware
        : [to.meta.middleware];

      for (const middleware of middlewares) {
        const result = await middleware(to, from);
        if (result !== undefined && result !== true) return result;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

`middleware/admin.ts`

```
type AppUser = { admin: boolean };
const LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_USER = "";
const ROUTE_ACCESS_DENIED = { path: "" };

export default function admin() {
  const user = localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_USER);

  if (!user) return;

  const appUser: AppUser = JSON.parse(user);

  if (appUser.admin !== true) return ROUTE_ACCESS_DENIED.path;
}
```

`middleware/auth.ts`

```
import { RouteLocationNormalized } from "vue-router";

const ROUTE_LOGIN = { path: "" };
const LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_USER = "";
const LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_PATH_BEFORE_LOGIN = "";

export default function auth(to: RouteLocationNormalized) {
  const user = !!localStorage.getItem(LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_USER);

  if (!user) {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCALSTORAGE_KEY_PATH_BEFORE_LOGIN, to.path);
    return ROUTE_LOGIN.path;
  }
}
```

Your code apparently `next` multiple times, which is not surprising given the complicatedness of all the recursion going on.
This is actually a source of bugs in and of itself, as it means that each middleware is trying to do its own redirect or whatever, which is a conflict you don't want.

I have made major changes, as you can see:

- Refactored it to just loop through the middleware functions, redirecting or cancelling the navigation on the first guard to do so.
- Refactored it to use `return`-style navigation guards (`next` should not be used; see [Vue Router Docs - Navigation Guards - Optional Third Argument Next](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#optional-third-argument-next)).
- Added handling for async guard functions.
- Attempted to improve typing where possible.

I am using placeholder types and values, as I obviously do not have access to your full project.

Comment: @ProgZi I'm not understanding what you're getting at?